# Dynamic database driven accordion in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using ASP.NET mvc4 with razor,i am trying to create accordion control dynamically by reading the values from the database. Could someone please point me to the example code on how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the sample of accordion [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/)

here what you can do in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using(var db=new YourDataContext())
    {
         List<YourTableModel> details=db.YourTable.ToList();
         return View(details)
    }
}
```

and in your view assuming that the table you have contains Title and Description data

```
@model IEnumerable<YourTableModel>

<dl class="accordion">

@foreach(var detail in Model)
{
<dt><a href="">@detail.Title</a></dt>
<dd>@detail.Description</dd>
}
</dl>
```